# Replace strings globaly from an array pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, loops

I'm trying to replace multi characters from array globally with regular expresion, but it just replace the first character for me:

```js
var ARABIC_PUNC_AND_REPLACEMENTS = [
    [
      ',', // Comma
      ';', // Semicolon
    ],
    [
      '،', // Comma
      '؛', // Semicolon
    ]
  ];

var string = ',,, ;;;';

for (var i = 0; i < ARABIC_PUNC_AND_REPLACEMENTS[0].length; i++) {
   string = string.replace(ARABIC_PUNC_AND_REPLACEMENTS[0][i], ARABIC_PUNC_AND_REPLACEMENTS[1][i]);
}

console.log(string); // "،,, ؛;;"
// I want this to be returnd: "،،، ؛؛؛"
```

Comment: Please search before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct a `RegExp` and pass `global` flag like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ARABIC_PUNC_AND_REPLACEMENTS[0].length; i++) {
   string = string.replace(new RegExp(ARABIC_PUNC_AND_REPLACEMENTS[0][i], 'g'),
     ARABIC_PUNC_AND_REPLACEMENTS[1][i]);
}

console.log(string);
//=> "،،، ؛؛؛"
```

Comment: Working!, Thank you @anubhava